# What is Mio's behaviour on a Poll with a zero duration timeout?

Tags: rust, mio

According to the [`mio::Poll` docs](https://docs.rs/mio/0.6.14/mio/struct.Poll.html):

> The function will block until either at least one readiness event has been received or timeout has elapsed. A timeout of None means that poll will block until a readiness event has been received.
>   ...
>   Note that the timeout will be rounded up to the system clock granularity (usually 1ms), and kernel scheduling delays mean that the blocking interval may be overrun by a small amount.

Meanwhile, Linux's [`select()` has the zero timeout feature](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html):

> If both fields of the timeval structure are zero, then select() returns immediately.  (This is useful for polling.)

What is Mio's behaviour on a `Duration::from_secs(0)`, would it work like Linux's `select()`?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want a Linux answer cause you link to a Linux manual.

`mio` [uses `epoll()`, not `select()`, on Linux](https://github.com/carllerche/mio/blob/c419ed6ef3bb00314251d3ba5e6f2c01f3997225/src/poll.rs#L294-L300):

```
/// |      OS    |  Selector |
/// |------------|-----------|
/// | Linux      | [epoll]   |
/// | OS X, iOS  | [kqueue]  |
/// | Windows    | [IOCP]    |
/// | FreeBSD    | [kqueue]  |
/// | Android    | [epoll]   |
```

And the relevant quote from `epoll()` is:

> The timeout argument specifies the minimum number of milliseconds that epoll_wait() will block. (This interval will be rounded up to the system clock granularity, and kernel scheduling delays mean that the blocking interval may overrun by a small amount.) Specifying a timeout of -1 causes epoll_wait() to block indefinitely, while specifying a timeout equal to zero cause epoll_wait() to return immediately, even if no events are available.

So, `Duration::from_secs(0)` will not wait for incoming event. You can check the code of `mio` [here](https://github.com/carllerche/mio/blob/c419ed6ef3bb00314251d3ba5e6f2c01f3997225/src/sys/unix/epoll.rs#L65-L67)

```
let timeout_ms = timeout
            .map(|to| cmp::min(millis(to), i32::MAX as u64) as i32)
            .unwrap_or(-1);
```

We can see that the behavior of `mio` will copy the behavior of `epoll()`.

Comment: I  wonder if you know why that code quoted in your last paragraph does the `as u64` and then back with `as i32`. Why not keep it `i32` through the whole expression?

Comment: @ZanLynx `millis()` return an `u64`, In order to avoid overflow because timeout is an C `int` (they suppose C `int` has 32 bits), they compare this value to `i32::MAX` to do that need to first cast it to u64, then they take the minimum, so the final result is positive and can't overflow an `i32`.